# @Autowired bean is null when referenced in the constructor

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

When I reference the bean from the constructor it is null, but when referenced from another method it is fine.

Comment: You'd really benefit from providing some more details. Any code you can share?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335975/autowired-bean-is-null-when-referenced-in-the-constructor-of-another-bean

tldr: try using @PostConstruct if you need access to beans during class initialization

Answer (score 0):

To refer a bean in a constructor, you need to

1. Annotate the constructor with `@Autowired`
2. Pass the bean as a parameter to the constructor

More details can be diagnosed if you share some sample code.