# How to use certain constants only once in a class instead of writing it individually in methods?

Tags: java, spring, constants, autowired

```html
class A
{
m1()
{
constant loading logic;
}
m2()
{
constant loading logic;
}
}

class B
{

@Autowired A a;

m3()
{
a.m1();
a.m2();
}

}
```

For clarity constant loading logic is :

```html
@Autowired
private Environment env; //spring environment
String accessKey = env.getProperty("aws_access_key");
 String secretKey = env.getProperty("aws_secret_access_key");
```

I have a class A which has a @Component spring annotation.class A is an @autowired property for another class B.
class A has 2 methods m1 and m2. class B calls m1 and m2.

I want to load certain common properties(constants) and use these constants in both m1 and m2.Is there an efficient way to do this **instead of repeating the same constant loading logic** to be written in both methods m1 and m2 ?

Comment: It's really unclear what the constants have to do with anything else at this point. If you could give sample code demonstrating the problem, it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: They are access keys and other keys that need to be set in both m1 and m2..

Comment: Can you load it in class A default (no arguments) constructor ?

Comment: It's still far less clear written as a description than it would be in sample code. We still don't know what "constant loading logic" is being repeated

Comment: updated the question..:)

Comment: Oh, you didn't say that constant lading logic also requires an autowired bean. Then forget my previous comment and see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6336013/4358405 (the other answer there should work too)

Comment: @TMG can you please look at the update and edit it with your answer.I am not understanding your link...

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
class A{
  String accessKey;
  String secretKey;

  @Autowired
  public A(Environment env){
    accessKey = env.getProperty("aws_access_key");
    secretKey = env.getProperty("aws_secret_access_key");
  }
  public void m1(){
    // whatever logic here
  }
  public void m2(){
    // whatever logic here
  }
}
```

Comment: so from class B..i always have to call the class A constructor (by creating an object everytime) before invoking m1 and m2 ?

Comment: nope, you can just autowire A in B and Spring should be able to call A's constructor

Comment: Throwing exception:error creating bean with name A...could not find default constructor...I just autowired A in B like this @Autowired public  A a; .Default constructor is not able to be autowired.

Comment: Did you annotated A's constructor with @Autowired, like in my example above? Just to double check I've copy pasted A class from my answer and autowired it in another bean. Works fine for me :-)

Comment: copy paste your autowired field in B.Is it public or private ?