# When Does Creation, Registration and Injection in Spring IOC Occur?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I am trying to figure out at what juncture does creation, registration and injection of beans in Spring IOC occur with `annotation-config` and `@Autowired`. I have the following test setup which is puzzling me because I don't see injections happening for the setter methods, but the bean properties do get set:

**ActiveUser**:

```
package com.example;

public class ActiveUser { 
  public ActiveUser() {
    System.out.println("Active User Created -> " + this);
  }
}
```

**MiscUser:**

```
package com.example;

public class MiscUser {     
    public MiscUser() {
        System.out.println("Misc User Created -> " + this);
    }
}
```

**TopUser:**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required;

public class TopUser {

    private ActiveUser activeUser;

    private MiscUser miscUser;

    public TopUser() {
        System.out.println("Top User Created -> " + this);
        System.out.println("Setting Active User in constructor -> " + this.activeUser);
        System.out.println("Setting Misc User in constructor -> " + this.miscUser);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setActiveUser(ActiveUser activeUser) {
        System.out.println("Setting Active User -> " + this.activeUser);
        this.activeUser = activeUser;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Required
    public void setMiscUser(MiscUser miscUser) {
        System.out.println("Setting Misc User -> " + this.miscUser);
        this.miscUser = miscUser;
    }

    public ActiveUser getActiveUser() {
        return activeUser;
    }

    public MiscUser getMiscUser() {
        return miscUser;
    }

}
```

**applicationContext.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       ">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="activeUser" class="com.example.ActiveUser"></bean>
    <bean id="miscUser" class="com.example.MiscUser"></bean>

    <bean id="topUser" class="com.example.TopUser"></bean>

</beans>
```

**Main method class**:

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Executor {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Start Context ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:com/example/applicationContext.xml");
        getContextInfo(context);        
        checkTopUser(context);
        System.out.println("\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ End Context ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    }

    private static void checkTopUser(ApplicationContext context) {
        TopUser tu = (TopUser) context.getBean(TopUser.class);
        if (tu.getActiveUser() == null) {
            System.out.println("TU's Active User is null!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Retrieving Active User -> " + tu.getActiveUser());
        }
        if (tu.getMiscUser() == null) {
            System.out.println("TU's Misc User is null!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Retrieving Misc User -> " + tu.getMiscUser());
        }
    }
}
```

The surprisingly part is that I don't see `TopUser`'s properties being injected through setter methods based on the output, however, they are still being injected when `TopUser` bean is retrieved from the context:

```
Active User Created -> com.example.ActiveUser@5c5a1b69
Misc User Created -> com.example.MiscUser@3701eaf6
Top User Created -> com.example.TopUser@1f36e637
Setting Active User in constructor -> null
Setting Misc User in constructor -> null
Setting Misc User -> null
Setting Active User -> null

Retrieving Active User -> com.example.ActiveUser@5c5a1b69
Retrieving Misc User -> com.example.MiscUser@3701eaf6
```

Comment: Autowiring happens after the construction of an object.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6336013/1679484

Comment: @NuCradle this is helpful article : (https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-autowired-annotation-example-with-setter-method-field-and-constructor-using-xml-and-java-configuration) **@Autowired Annotation Example with Setter Method**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change as follows, instead of

```
@Autowired
    public void setActiveUser(ActiveUser activeUser) {
        System.out.println("Setting Active User -> " + this.activeUser);
        this.activeUser = activeUser;
}
```

1st option : (print after(not before) setting instance variable)

```
    @Autowired
    public void setActiveUser(ActiveUser activeUser) {
        this.activeUser = activeUser;
        System.out.println("Setting Active User -> " + this.activeUser);

}
```

2nd option : (grab method argument variable, rather than instance variable)

```
@Autowired
public void setActiveUser(ActiveUser activeUser) {
    this.activeUser = activeUser;
    System.out.println("Setting Active User -> " + activeUser);
}
```

---

Actually there is easier way to achieve your objective : you can ask Spring to notify you whenever bean is initialized through lifecycle methods. One way to do it is to implement `InitializingBean` interface in each bean, override `afterPropertiesSet()` method and output anything you like. `afterPropertiesSet()` will be called by container once bean is initialized and wired with all it's dependencies.

Comment: Well, that was a dumb mistake. Thanks for catching it. :)

Comment: @NuCradle Welcome!