# How to access @Autowired fields in Vaadin views configuration in Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, vaadin, autowired

I have a class looking like this:

```
@Route(value = "dashboard", layout = MainView::class)
@PageTitle("Dashboard")
class DashboardView : VerticalLayout() {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var someService: someService

    init {
        val grids = HorizontalLayout()
        grids.justifyContentMode = FlexComponent.JustifyContentMode.CENTER
        grids.alignItems = FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER

        // initialize some grids with data from someService

        grids.setSizeFull()

        add(grids)
        setSizeFull()
        justifyContentMode = FlexComponent.JustifyContentMode.CENTER
        alignItems = FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER
    }

    companion object {
        const val VIEW_NAME = "Dashboard"
    }
}
```

someService is some class annotated with Spring `@Service` annotation which injects `someRepository` to access database data.

The problem is that someService cannot be initialized before init block called and seems to be null.

I use Spring version 3.0.2 and Vaadin version 23.

I tried some tricks with `@SpringView` or `@SpringComponent` annotations, bit still have no idea how to inject this service and make it visible from my UIView init block.

Comment: Use constructor injection. Keep in mind Spring (Boot?) 3 is not compatible with Vaadin 23

Comment: Use `@PostConstruct` or do your work in `onAttach`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@Autowired bean is null when referenced in the constructor of another bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335975/autowired-bean-is-null-when-referenced-in-the-constructor-of-another-bean)